# how to overlay an admob ad without shifting my Layout xml

Tags: java, android, admob

I am having an issue with admob ads affecting my layout.
my current app, has limited space for adding an admob ad the conventional way at the top or bottom (which I can do without issues). 
What I am trying to do is overlay the ad on top of my layout, without the screen shifting 
down or up, which would mess up my layout.
any help is appreciated. Thx

Comment: to follow up, I have seen something like this done in the angry birds app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` that will wrap your current layout + the adview and then you could position the ad where you want.